# How do you Group, Sort, and Extract 2nd Highest Quantity from Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to group a pandas dataframe according to customer, sort it according to quantity, and return the entire row containing the 2nd highest value for quantity.

I have something like this:

```
  customer  item  quantity 
0        A     p         5
1        A     p         8
2        A     q         9
3        A     q         2
4        B     p         3
5        B     p         6
```

I'm able to return a dataframe containing the rows with the maximum quantity. I used:

```
idx=df.groupby(by='customer')['quantity'].idxmax()
df_max=df.loc[idx,]
```

This returned the following Dataframe:

```
  customer  item  quantity
2        A     q         9
5        B     p         6
```

However, I also need a Dataframe with the second-highest quantity, and I'm stumped.

I'd like a Dataframe returned that looks like this:

```
  customer  item  quantity
1        A     p         8
4        B     p         3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) to take the nth row from a sorted dataframe, note the index starts from 0.

```py
out = (df.sort_values('quantity', ascending=False)
       .groupby('customer', as_index=False).nth(1))
```

```
print(out)

  customer item  quantity
1        A    p         8
4        B    p         3
```

Comment: Nice reminder on `nth` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby("customer").agg({'quantity': list}).apply(lambda x: sorted(x.quantity)[-2], axis=1)
```